# How to write lazy functions which are chainable, in python?

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

I want to write functions which are lazy as well as chainable. What would be the best way.
I know that one way would be to do `yield` instead of `return`.

I want these functions to be lazy in the way similar to how sqlalchemy functions are lazy when asked to fetch the data from DB.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generators (functions with `yield` instead of `return`) can indeed be seen as "lazy" (and `itertools.chain` can chain them just as well as any other iterator, if that's what you mean by "chainable").

But if by "chainable" (and lazy) you mean you want to call `fee().fie().fo().fum()` and have all the "hard work" happen only in `fum` (which seems closer to what SQLAlchemy does), then generators won't help -- what you need, rather, is the "Promise" design pattern, where each function/method (except the one actually doing all the work) returns an object which records all the conditions, parameters, and constraints on the operation, and the one hard-working function uses that information to finally perform the work.

To give a very simple example, say that "the hard work" is performing an RPC call of the form `remote(host, **kwargs)`. You could dress this up in "lazy chainable clothing" as follows:

```
class RPC(object):
    def __init__(self, host):
        self._host = host
        self._kws = {}
    def doit(self, **morekws):
        return remote(self._host, **dict(self._kws, **morekws))
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def setkw(value):
            self._kws[name] = value
            return self
        return setkw
```

Now, `RPC(x).foo('bar').baz('bap').doit()` calls `remote(x, foo=bar, baz=bap)` (and of course you can save intermediate stages of the chain, pass them around as arguments, etc, etc, until the call to `doit`).

Comment: can something similar be done with functions alone, without using classes?

Comment: @roopesh, each function call has to return an object of _some_ type, which allows "chaining", i.e. calling further arbitrary methods on it: what built-in type do you have in mind that would allow you to call arbitrary method on its instances? There are none -- each built-in type has a well defined set of methods, and you cannot call on its instances methods other than those, of course. So, it obviously **has** to be a user-coded type... which is also known as "a class". The "chainable" constraint is clearly the main determinant of this -- whatever reason you had for setting it.